# Regex - stack trace - match all website addresses other than java package name

Tags: java, regex, string

I came up with a regex that matches websites without having the leading http:// or  https://. Now, I'm trying to do this on stack traces where I expect it to catch only actual websites but the regex is also catching java class name of the format com.abc.xyz also.

Generally all these are preceded by either at (or) is and I need help with writing a negative lookahead. Or we can also eliminate this if we see a com or org at the front.

Now, I have this regex. `(?!at) [a-z\.-]*\.(com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|us|uk|au|in|ca|eu|ke)`
I'm not sure how to add the "at" for the negative lookahead. This is just catching one word of a/t.

Few examples,

client.DefaultHttpClient : I/O exception (org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException) caught when connecting to {}-> Connect to scn.sap.com timed out ==>  gives scn.sap.com

But this 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) returns  java.net which I don't want it to.

Can you please help me with the first part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would `com.foocompany.FooClass` match your regex? Classes will almost never end in `.com`, so your regex is already filtering reverse http address package names from real http addresses. (although you just a tiny fraction of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains )

Comment: Yes you are right, it will not match for your example. But if we have a java.net or some class.catalina its going to match as it has .net and .ca

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that `at` appears at the beginning of the line, exclude it specifically. Then do a non-greedy search forward until you hit your match pattern:

```
^(?!^at).*? ([a-z\.-]*\.(?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|us|uk|au|in|ca|eu|ke))
```

You can see this using your given sample text [at regex101.com here](https://regex101.com/r/uM4oU0/1).

Comment: Hi OnlineCop, Thanks a lot for your regex. I was trying for multiple strings and when I tried for the string - "exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: foo.page.com" it matched java.net but not foo.page.java. Can you please suggest a modification on this regex. Thanks

Comment: Remove the `?` from the `.*?` so it becomes greedy. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/uM4oU0/2).